# What is cx Oracle data type for BOOLEAN?

Tags: python, plsql, cx-oracle

From http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html, I am not able to find cx Oracle data type for BOOLEAN.

Thanks,

Comment: Last time I worked on Oracle, there wasn't a boolean data type

Answer (score 1):

There is no data type for Boolean. However, you can use int(True) or int(False) to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the Oracle database itself there is no such datatype, although there is a BOOLEAN type available when coding in PL/SQL.  When I need a Yes/No field in a database table I use a CHAR(1) field constrained to hold 'Y' or 'N'; similarly, if I really need a True/False value I'll use a CHAR(1) constrained to hold 'T' or 'F'.

Share and enjoy.